# Why is this not showing buttons in gridlayout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, grid-layout

Im trying to create the so called "15 game" , which is like a slide puzzle with 16 buttons, 15 of them with numbers 1-15 and a empty one. Clicking on a button next to the empty one will switch position with the clicked button and the empty one. BUt now I am trying to set up the gui, which is made with Swing, gridlayout and 16 buttons. BUt i cant make it to work, here is my code:

```
package game;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class TheGame{



public static void main(String[] args){

    TheGame game = new TheGame();

}


public TheGame(){

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("15Game");
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4,4,3,3);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    Cell cell1 = new Cell("1");
    Cell cell2 = new Cell("2");
    Cell cell3 = new Cell("3");
    Cell cell4 = new Cell("4");
    Cell cell5 = new Cell("5");

    Cell cell6 = new Cell("6");
    Cell cell7 = new Cell("7");
    Cell cell8 = new Cell("8");
    Cell cell9 = new Cell("9");
    Cell cell10 = new Cell("10");

    Cell cell11 = new Cell("11");
    Cell cell12 = new Cell("12");
    Cell cell13 = new Cell("13");
    Cell cell14 = new Cell("14");
    Cell cell15 = new Cell("15");

    Cell cellEmpty = new Cell("");

    panel.add(cell1);
    panel.add(cell2);
    panel.add(cell3);
    panel.add(cell4);
    panel.add(cell5);

    panel.add(cell6);
    panel.add(cell7);
    panel.add(cell8);
    panel.add(cell9);
    panel.add(cell10);

    panel.add(cell11);
    panel.add(cell12);
    panel.add(cell13);
    panel.add(cell14);
    panel.add(cell15);

    panel.add(cellEmpty);

    panel.setLayout(grid);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

And here is Cell:

```
package game;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Cell extends JButton {

//Variables

public Cell(String s){

    this.setText(s);

}
```

When i create this, it only pop up a small empty gui window, with no buttons at all. Why is that, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Call `panel.setLayout()` __before__ you start adding buttons. What the layout does is tell the panel where the buttons go when you add them. If you add the layout after the buttons, it doesn't do much good. You also want to add the panel to the frame or it also isn't gonna do much good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the panel that contains the buttons to the frame

```
frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: IT works now, thank you, but It is very small. Can i use setSize(new Dimension(x,y)) to resize the buttons?

Comment: @user3079108 It is most likely small because of the layout you are using on the frame. Did you change it? The default layout on a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, which shouldn't suppress the size of the frame, as long as you add it to `BorderLayout.CENTER`, which can be done by adding another parameter to `add` like so: `frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`.

Comment: You can also try having Cell extend JFrame instead and add the button to that and then add in insets and a border as well to increase the cell size

Comment: @user3079108 Avoid using `setSize`. Override `getPreferredSize` for the panel itself. Actually there's no need to subclass `JButton`, just create instance & use